# "To brought" doesn't sound right but the sentence is in the past tense

Tags: prepositions, past-tense

I'm a non-native English speaker writing a short story and I would like to confirm if this sentence is correct or not.

> "She closed her eyes and took a deep, calming breath *to bring* down
> her rage."

I feel something is off in this sentence. So the narrative is mainly done in the past tense, however, making the verb 'bring' to 'brought' sounds wrong. Google doc also flags 'brought' as wrong and it wants me to change it back to 'bring'.

'to bring' seems to be a preposition + present tense form but making it to preposition + past tense, "to brought" sounds really odd even though the narrative is in the past.

May I know why "to brought" sounds odd or is it actually correct?

Thanks.

Comment: To bring is correct—the infinitive doesn’t inflect.

Comment: @Xanne - I see. I just read on infinitive and it does sound you're right. Just a clarification, does this mean that when a verb is in the infinitive form, it will retain its present form even though if the sentence is in the past tense? Thanks.

Comment: Right, it stays the same.

Comment: @Xanne - Awesome! Thanks for clarifying that up. If you could put it as an answer, I can vote it and flag it as the answer to my question. :) Again thanks!

Comment: There’s a detailed answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382078/why-doesnt-the-verb-need-to-have-s-in-this-sentence/382082#382082

Comment: Why not make it more concise ? "She closed her eyes and took a deep breath to calm her rage"

Comment: @JerardDelaVictoria Infinitives don’t have a tense. It is just a (confusing) coincidence in English that the infinitive usually happens to be spelled the same way as the present simple.